# How to use Salesforce OAuth session ID for Metadata API?

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, oauth, auth

I am using the REST API for my application. But I also need to use Metadata API. So for Metadata API calls I am trying to use the Session ID of OAuth authentication. For now I am able to use the session id for SOAP api calls but when I call a  metadata method I get this error:  "INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session"

Here is my code:

```
try{
 $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');

  $serverUrl = "$instance_url/services/Soap/u/27.0/00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $sessionId = $_SESSION['access_token'];
  $mySforceConnection->setSessionHeader($sessionId);
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->attach($serverUrl, $sessionId);

  $myMetadataConnection = new    SforceMetadataClient(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/metadata.wsdl.xml', $myLogin, $mySforceConnection);

  /*--These 3 lines of code works fine ----*/

   $query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone from Contact";

    $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
    print_r($response);

   /*--------------------------------------*/

    $customField = new SforceCustomField();

    $customField->setFullName('Contact.MyCustomFieldb__c');
    $customField->setDescription('Description of New Field');

   $customField->setLabel('My Custom Field Label');

   $customField->setType('Text');
   $customField->setFormula('HYPERLINK(Password__c , "The Name")');
     $customField->setLength(100);
  //Contact->nameField=$customField;

 /*-----------This line giving the Error----------*/
    print_r($myMetadataConnection->create($customField));

  } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $myMetadataConnection->getLastRequest();
     echo $e->faultstring;  
  }
```

Code of `attach` method:

```
public function attach($url, $sid) {
   $this->sessionId = $sid;
   $this->setSessionHeader($this->sessionId);
   $serverURL = $url;
   $this->setEndPoint($serverURL);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `attach` method? I don't see it in the PHP Toolkit.

Comment: @metadaddy I read a blog post where the writer used 'attach' method. On contacting him he provide me the PHP toolkit having 'attach' method. This is link to post. [link](http://techsahre.blogspot.com/2012/10/oauth-token-as-salesforce-sessionid-in.html)

Comment: Could you post the `attach` code in the question? I don't see it anywhere online.

Comment: @metadaddy yes sure... I edit my question and include code for `attach` method in the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in the above code:

1. `attach()` does not return a `LoginResult`, so the `SforceMetadataClient` doesn't get a session id.
2. The Metadata API has a different endpoint from the SOAP Partner API (`m` in the URL in place of `u`).
3. You can't set a length on Formula Fields.

Making those corrections, your code should look like this (my changes marked out with ***):

```
try{
    $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');

    $serverUrl = "$instance_url/services/Soap/u/27.0/00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $sessionId = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $mySforceConnection->setSessionHeader($sessionId);
    $mySforceConnection->attach($serverUrl, $sessionId);

    // *** Metadata API is on its own endpoint
    $metadataServerUrl = "$instance_url/services/Soap/m/27.0/00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // *** Make an object with the fields that the SforceMetadataClient constructor expects
    $myLogin = new stdclass();
    $myLogin->sessionId = $sessionId;
    $myLogin->metadataServerUrl = $metadataServerUrl;

    $myMetadataConnection = new    SforceMetadataClient(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/metadata.wsdl.xml', $myLogin, $mySforceConnection);

    /*--These 3 lines of code works fine ----*/

    $query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone from Contact";

    $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
    print_r($response);

    /*--------------------------------------*/

    $customField = new SforceCustomField();

    $customField->setFullName('Contact.MyCustomFieldb__c');
    $customField->setDescription('Description of New Field');

    $customField->setLabel('My Custom Field Label');

    $customField->setType('Text');
    $customField->setFormula('HYPERLINK(Password__c , "The Name")');
    // *** Don't set length on a FormulaField
    // $customField->setLength(100);
    //Contact->nameField=$customField;

    /*-----------This line giving the Error----------*/
    print_r($myMetadataConnection->create($customField))
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $myMetadataConnection->getLastRequest();
    echo $e->faultstring;  
}
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [done] => 
            [id] => 04sE0000002GfQ0IAK
            [numberComponentErrors] => 0
            [numberComponentsDeployed] => 0
            [numberComponentsTotal] => 0
            [numberTestErrors] => 0
            [numberTestsCompleted] => 0
            [numberTestsTotal] => 0
            [state] => InProgress
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you @metadaddy. It worked fine and solved lot of my problems. :)